# Cannot access a directive before initialization. Reference error

Tags: angular

I have an Angular module with a static function called `forRoot()` that receives an object as a parameter and a service with a parameter in the constructor called `@Inject(FOR_ROOT_CONFIG_DHDIRECTIVES) private config: DirectivesConfig`.

This service is called in a directive and when I call this directive in my project, ocurrs an ReferenceError:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AccessControlDirective' before initialization
> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AccessControlDirective' before initialization

I have noticed that if I remove the @Inject parameter from the service, there is no error.

This is my module:

```js
export var FOR_ROOT_CONFIG_DHDIRECTIVES = 'DHDirectivesConfig';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AccessControlDirective,
  ],
  exports: [
    AccessControlDirective,
  ],
})
export class DhDirectivesModule {
  static forRoot(
    config: DirectivesConfig
  ): ModuleWithProviders<DhDirectivesModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: DhDirectivesModule,
      providers: [
        DhDirectivesService,
        {
          provide: FOR_ROOT_CONFIG_DHDIRECTIVES,
          useValue: config,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

My Service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DhDirectivesService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(FOR_ROOT_CONFIG_DHDIRECTIVES) private config: DirectivesConfig
  ) {}


  exists(id: number | string): void {
    // return this.config.actions.some(
    //   (x) => String(x[this.config.propId]) == String(id)
    // );
  }
}
```

My Directive:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[dhAccessControl]',
})
export class AccessControlDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private _directiveService: DhDirectivesService,
    private elRef: ElementRef
  ) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    debugger;
    this.elRef.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
    this.check();
  }

  @Input('dhAccessControlIdOpcion') idOpcion: string = null;

  /**
   * Verifica si existe la opción si no, remueve el elemento del DOM
   */
  checkId() {
    // const id: number = parseInt(this.idOpcion);
    // const existeAccion = this._directiveService.exists(id);
    // if (existeAccion) {
    //   this.elRef.nativeElement.style.display = 'inline';
    // } else {
    //   this.elRef.nativeElement.remove();
    // }
  }
}
```

Also if I remove the `DhDirectivesService` reference from the directive, there is no reference error

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself.

I was doing the dependency injection wrong, so I had to change everything.
In my service I removed the `@Inject` and left only the name of the object `constructor (private config: DirectivesConfig)`
and remove `@Injectable` decorator in my service

In the module I changed the providers in the forRoot method:

```js
providers: [
 {
   provide: DhDirectivesService,
   useClass: DhDirectivesService,
   useValue: config,
 },
],
```

And it no longer generates reference errors in the directive where I am using the service